# Google apps script Pdf encryption How to generate secured PDF on Google App Engine?

Tags: pdf, encryption, google-apps-script

I wish to generate a secured PDF from a spreadsheet, In particular, setting up the security options to prevent copying.

So far, I generate PDFs like this:

```
function convert(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var id = ss.getId(); 
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=pdf',googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob();//pdf
  DocsList.createFile(doc).rename('pdfexport.pdf');
  var pdffileID = DocsList.createFile(doc).getId()  
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(pdffileID);
  Logger.log("file type : "+file.getFileType());
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope){
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Is there a way to generate a secured PDF file from Google Drive or isn't it supported?

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like this is supported directly.  Depending on the use case, you could share a read only copy of the document in Google Docs.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,I appriciate your response. I'm attaching the document in email and want it to be pdf and copy protected