# Add encryption to converted Google sheet to PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

Is it possible to encrypt a converted google sheet into PDF before sending it as an attachment in an email ?

This is my current code: It hides the sheet I don't need to be converted and converting the other sheet into PDF. What I would like to achieve here is for the converted PDF to be password encrypted because it contains some personal information.

```
function myFunction() {
  Utilities.sleep(200);

  var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
  var pdfsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");

  sheet.hideSheet();

  var substringsubject = pdfsheet.getRange("B4:B4").getValues();
  var substringnname = pdfsheet.getRange("B3:B3").getValues();
  var substringidnum = pdfsheet.getRange("B7:B7").getValues();

  var startRow =9;  // First row of data to process B9:B9
  var numRows =1;   // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells B9:B9
  var dataRange = pdfsheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var email = row[1];
    var emailcc = row[2];
    // Subject of email message
    var subject = "USER ACCOUNT DETAILS " + substringsubject + " " + substringidnum + ""; 
    var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
    // Email Body can  be HTML too 
    var body =    '<body>' + ' Hi ' + substringnname +',<br><br>' +
    'Please see attached file for your account details.</p>' +
    //'<p>  Click <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a> to go to google.<p>'
    '</body>'  

    var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getId()).getAs("application/pdf"); 
    pdf.setName(substringsubject+" "+substringidnum+" .pdf");
    // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment  
    MailApp.sendEmail({
       to:email, 
       cc:emailcc,
       subject:subject, 
       htmlBody:body,
       attachments:[pdf]
    });
    sheet.showSheet();  
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't protect your PDF directly from Apps script. See this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188312/google-apps-script-pdf-encryption-how-to-generate-secured-pdf-on-google-app-engi).

Comment: oh I see i thought it would have been implemented because it was a question 3 years ago. Thanks